# Trying to type a decision tree for two-player games

Tags: idris

I want to construct a decision tree for a two-player game (e.g. Tic-Tac-Toe) whose type ensures that it is complete. That is, I want the type of a tree's node to ensure that its children are exactly all of its successor nodes.

Here's my attempt at doing this in Idris. Tic-Tac-Toe is complicated so I made a much simpler game: there are three positions to move at (`A | B | C`), and the game ends after one move.

`DTNode` is "decision tree node."

```
data Player = Computer | Human
Eq Player where
  Computer == Computer = True
  Human == Human = True
  _ == _ = False
Show Player where
  show Computer = "Computer"
  show Human = "Human"
opponent : Player -> Player
opponent Computer = Human
opponent Human = Computer

data Position = A | B | C
Move : Type
Move = (Player, Position)

State : Type
State = List Move
isFinal : State -> Bool
isFinal (a::_) = True
isFinal _ = False
successorStates : State -> (toMove: Player) -> List State
successorStates s toMove = case (isFinal s) of
  True =>
    []

  False =>
    [(toMove, A)::s, (toMove, B)::s, (toMove, C)::s]

mutual
  SuccessorDTNodeType : (s : State) -> (toMove: Player) -> (successors: List State) -> Type
  SuccessorDTNodeType _ _ [] = the Type ()
  SuccessorDTNodeType s toMove (successor::rest) = DTNode successor (opponent toMove) oneLevelDownNodeType -> SuccessorDTNodeType s toMove rest where
    oneLevelDownNodeType = SuccessorDTNodeType successor (opponent $ opponent toMove) (successorStates successor toMove)

  data DTNode : (s: State) -> (toMove: Player) -> SuccessorDTNodeType s toMove (successorStates s toMove) -> Type where
```

I'm getting the following type error:

```
   |
45 |     oneLevelDownNodeType = SuccessorDTNodeType successor (opponent $ opponent toMove) (successorStates successor toMove)
   |                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
When checking right hand side of Main.SuccessorDTNodeType, oneLevelDownNodeType with expected type
        SuccessorDTNodeType successor (opponent toMove) (successorStates successor (opponent toMove))

Type mismatch between
        Type (Type of SuccessorDTNodeType successor (opponent (opponent toMove)) (successorStates successor toMove))
and
        SuccessorDTNodeType successor
                            (opponent toMove)
                            (case isFinal successor of
                               True => []
                               False => [(toMove, A) :: s, (toMove, B) :: s, (toMove, C) :: s]) (Expected type)
```

I only slightly understand; my guess is that `Type`, the return type of `SuccessorDTNodeType`, is not specific enough to meet the demands of my `DTNode` constructor.

Is this the case, and if so is there something I can do to get around it?